# Receiving packets with raw socket in Linux

Tags: raw-sockets

I am really new to sockets. I use raw socket because I am waiting for a UDP packet but I don't know from which port it will arrive. I found code here: http://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-c-linux/. I changed socket to: sock_raw = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_UDP) to see only UDP. It works only when I am surfing to Internet with browser - I see all DNS replays. But when I try to receive UDP packet from another PC it doesn't work. In wireshark I see that packet and ICMP request:"port is not unreachable" that is created by my PC. WHat may be a problem???? Thanks a lot!
By the way I use Ubuntu 12.04, Eclipse 3.7.2.